# Data analysis over geometric distribution sample with R (statistics pack)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, computational-mathematics, data-analysis

**Problem :**

The following observations are the number of tries $21$ football players had to make until they succeeded in scoring a penalty kick. Consider that all players have equal skills.

> $$3 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 3 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 2 \quad 2 \quad 2 \quad 5 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 5 \quad 2 \quad 3$$

**(i)** Find analytically the Maximum Likelihood Estimator of the success rate of each player regarding the penalty kicks.

**(ii)** Find graphically the Maximum Likelihood Estimator of the success rateo f each player regarding the penalty kicks, with the help of $\mathbf{R}$ (statistics pack-language)

**Attempt :**

**(ii)** One can easily see that the case of the specific problem leads to the conclusion that the observations follow the ***Geometric Distribution*** as it follows exactly by its definition (the number of trials $x$ needed until the first success). Thus, the Maximum Likelihood Estimator can be found us (Loglikelihood) :

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ with p.d.f. $f(x;p)=(1-p)^{x_1}p, \; x=1,2,\dots$ .The likelihood function is given by :
>   $$L\left(p \right)={\left(1-p \right)}^{{x}_{1}-1}p {\left(1-p \right)}^{{x}_{2}-1}p...{\left(1-p \right)}^{{x}_{n}-1}p ={p}^{n}{\left(1-p \right)}^{\sum_{1}^{n}{x}_{i}-n}$$
>   By applying the natural logarithm, we get :
>   $$\ln L\left(p \right)= n\ln{p}+\left(\sum_{1}^{n}{x}_{i}-n \right)\ln{\left(1-p \right)}$$
>   Following differentiation and equaling to zero, we yield :
>   $$\frac{d\left[\ln L\left(p \right)\right]}{dp}=\frac{n}{p} -\frac{\left(\sum_{1}^{n}{x}_{i}-n \right)}{\left(1-p \right)}=0 \Rightarrow p=\frac{n}{\left(\sum_{1}^{n}{x}_{i} \right)}$$
>   which means that the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (Loglikelihood as we applied the logarithm) is :
>   $$P = \frac{n}{\left(\sum_{1}^{n}{x}_{i} \right)} =  \frac{1}{\bar{X}}$$

With the help of the statistics pack $\mathbf{R}$, we can write a short function to compute any Geometric Distribution Loglikelihood we'd like :

[image]

which when we execute for a given vector $\mathbf{trials}$ with the given observations, it returns the wanted result.

**Question :** My question is about part **(ii)** though, as I am completely at loss on how to proceed on estimating-calculating the Maximum Likelihood Estimator graphically with $\mathbf{R}$, especially since this is a case of a discrete distribution. I would really appreciate any hint or thorough explanation on how to proceed with it.